# Extremely slow dataframe.write.csv in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe, which has been created by union of rows,

```
def group_acc_num_and_make_metrics(acc_list: List[str], data_frame: DataFrame):
    for acc_no in acc_list:
        rows = rows.union(metrics_df(data_frame.filter(data_frame.SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NBR == acc_no), acc_no))
    return row
```

**metrics_df creates a new dataframe with 109 columns, so the return type of this function is a dataframe with 109 columns and some rows**

Now when I want to save this dataframe to csv, it is taking a hell amount of time, the number of rows in this dataframe is only 70, and it takes around 10 minutes to write it to csv file. The number of partitioned csv files generated are also 70. Repartitioning/coalesce is also a very timeraking operation. Below is the code for saving it to csv

```
def split_test_train(data_frame: DataFrame, number_of_rows):
    golden_ratio = 0.1
    test_rows = int(number_of_rows * golden_ratio)
    train_rows = number_of_rows - test_rows
    test_x_df = data_frame.sample(golden_ratio)
    train_x_df = data_frame.sample(1-golden_ratio)
    test_y_df = test_x_df.select(test_x_df.san, test_x_df.is_fraud)
    train_y_df = train_x_df.select(test_x_df.san, test_x_df.is_fraud)
    def_path = data_output_path
    path = def_path + str(int(datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000))
    test_x_df.drop(test_x_df.is_fraud).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save(path + "/test_x")
    train_x_df.drop(test_x_df.is_fraud).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save(path + "/train_x")
    test_y_df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save(path + "test_y")
    train_y_df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save(path + "/train_y")
```